# Optional insert into database?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I apologize if my title was a bit general, but I currently have a journal app where the user can pick an image when making a new entry and insert it into a database, which gets shown in a recyclerview later.

```kotlin
class addFragment : Fragment(), EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks, EasyPermissions.RationaleCallbacks {
    lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap

    private val mJournalViewModel: JournalViewModel by viewModels()
    private val mSharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels()
    var currentDate: String? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false)

        // set menu
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        view.mood_spinner.onItemSelectedListener = mSharedViewModel.listener

        // Set date and time for currentDate
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm a")
        currentDate = sdf.format(Date())

        // Opens gallery when image button clicked, gets image
        view.image_et.setOnClickListener {
            readStorageTask()
            //Intent to pick image
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1001)
        }

        return view
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.clear()
    }

    // Handle result of picked image
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1001) {

            // Converts image URI to bitmap
            if (data != null && data.data != null) {
                val uri = data.data!!
                val inputStream = requireContext().contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
                val cursor = requireContext().contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
                cursor?.use { c ->
                    val nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        val name = c.getString(nameIndex)
                        inputStream?.let { inputStream ->
                            // create same file with same name
                            val file = File(requireContext().cacheDir, name)
                            val os = file.outputStream()
                            os.use {
                                inputStream.copyTo(it)
                            }
                            val bitmapUnprocessed = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath)
                            bitmap = resizedBitmap(bitmapUnprocessed)
                            preview_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                            image_et.text = "Image picked!"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Creates check mark at the top of the fragment
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_fragment_menu, menu)
    }

    // If the check mark is clicked, entry gets added
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(item.itemId == R.id.menu_add) {
            insertDataToDb()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }


    // uses below function to check if text is empty, and gets values from add fragment
    private fun insertDataToDb() {
        val mTitle = title_et.text.toString()
        val mMood = mood_spinner.selectedItem.toString()
        val mDescription = description_et.text.toString()
        val mDate = currentDate.toString()

        val validation = mSharedViewModel.verifyDataFromUser(mTitle, mDescription)
        if(validation) {
            val newData = JournalData(
                0,
                mTitle,
                parseMood(mMood),
                mDescription,
                mDate,
                bitmap
            )
            mJournalViewModel.insertData(newData)
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "New entry added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_addFragment_to_listFragment) // Jetpack Navigation
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "You have some empty fields.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

And this is the database these values are getting inserted into:

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "journal_table")
@Parcelize
data class JournalData(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int,
    var title: String,
    var mood: Mood,
    var description: String,
    var date: String,
    var image: Bitmap
): Parcelable
```

### Issue

If the user doesn't pick an image, my app crashes and doesn't work in general (as expected). Is there any way to make it so that the bitmap/image in each entry can just stay as null or empty when all the other values are being inserted without causing any errors?

Basically, I'm trying to make attaching an image when making a journal entry optional, but I'm not sure how I could do this.

I'm pretty new to using room databases and have been trying to figure out a solution for this for a few days now, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image is not taken then you can stop the insertion by adding check  before db insertion OR if you want to insert even if the image is null then you can simply add the default  value of bitmap in room  data entity class

```
var image: Bitmap?=null
```

Comment: This solved my issue! I also had to change my TypeConverters like this however since they couldn't handle null values either.